# Pegar Valor de array html com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

No código abaixo pego os valores armazenados em vários `<textarea>` com o uso da função `each`.
Mas gostaria de fazer o mesmo de outr forma, utilizando um `for`.

É possível pegar esses valores fazendo uma varredura com um `for`, como devo fazer?

```
$("textarea[name='arraytextArea[]']:not(:first)").each(function () {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementsByName("arraytextArea[]");

//Caso não queira o primeiro textarea basta iniciar a variavel i com 1:
for(i=1;i<textarea.length;i++){
  console.log(textarea[i]);
}
```

```html
<textarea name="arraytextArea[]" id="txt1">AAA</textarea>
<textarea name="arraytextArea[]" id="txt2">BBB</textarea>
<textarea name="arraytextArea[]" id="txt3">CCC</textarea>
```

Comment: obrigado!!!!!!!